# Ansible - How to add/modify PATH variable in CentOS?

Tags: centos, ansible

I'm trying to add `/usr/pgsql-10/bin` to `$PATH`, since I want everybody who uses the machine, to be able to run the `psql` command.

Tried to follow [this](https://coderwall.com/p/ynvi0q/updating-path-with-ansible-system-wide) example:

```
- name: add {{extra_path}} to path
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/environment
    state: present
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: 'PATH=(["]*)((?!.*?{{extra_path}}).*?)(["]*)$'
    line: "PATH=\1\2:{{extra_path}}\3"
```

First of all, I don't quite understand how should I exactly modify this.
Should I replace just the `extra_path` or the whole `{{extra_path}}` with my path (`/usr/pgsql-10/bin`).

I tried either way and I get different errors.
To makes matters worse, my `/etc/environment` doesn't even contain `PATH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare additional path only

```yaml
  vars:
    extra_path: /usr/pgsql-10/bin
```

The tasks below are based on the idea from [Response to updating PATH with ansible - system wide](https://coderwall.com/p/ynvi0q/updating-path-with-ansible-system-wide)

- If the file is at the controller test the local file

```yaml
    - name: 'Add {{ extra_path }} if PATH does not exist'
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/environment
        line: 'PATH="{{ extra_path }}"'
        insertafter: EOF
      when: lookup('file', '/etc/environment') is not search('^\s*PATH\s*=')

    - name: 'Add {{ extra_path }} to PATH'
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/environment
        regexp: 'PATH=(["])((?!.*?{{ extra_path }}).*?)(["])$'
        line: 'PATH=\1\2:{{ extra_path }}\3'
        backrefs: yes
```

- If the files are on the remote hosts fetch them first. To make the play idempotent don't report changes on fetching. Fit the destination to your needs

```yaml
    - name: 'Fetch /etc/environment to {{ playbook_dir }}/environments'
      fetch:
        src: /etc/environment
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/environments"
      changed_when: false

    - name: 'Add {{ extra_path }} if PATH does not exist'
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/environment
        line: 'PATH="{{ extra_path }}"'
        insertafter: EOF
      when: lookup('file', path) is not search('^\s*PATH\s*=')
      vars:
        path: "{{ path_items|path_join }}"
        path_items:
          - "{{ playbook_dir }}"
          - environments
          - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
          - etc/environment

    - name: 'Add {{ extra_path }} to PATH'
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/environment
        regexp: 'PATH=(["])((?!.*?{{ extra_path }}).*?)(["])$'
        line: 'PATH=\1\2:{{ extra_path }}\3'
        backrefs: yes
```

See [Python regex](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html#regular-expression-howto).

Comment: Thank you so much, it actually worked. The only thing I did differently is defining the variable inside the task after the `- name`

Comment: I'm not sure your lookup works. "Lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine" - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html

Comment: You're right. I added an example of how to fetch the files to test them locally.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another awesome solution:

```yaml
- name: Add a path to system-wide $PATH.
  ansible.builtin.copy:
    dest: /etc/profile.d/custom-path.sh
    content: 'PATH=$PATH:{{ path_var }}'
    mode: "0644"
```

In this case, `path_var` refers to the path you want to add to the system-wide `$PATH`. On the next login, you should see your custom path when you `echo $PATH`!

---

Credit: [Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/add-path-global-path-ansible)

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution using Ansible variables after gathering facts:

```
- name: "Add {{ new_path }} to PATH if not exists"
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: /etc/environment
    regexp: '^PATH="{{ ansible_env.PATH }}"'
    replace: 'PATH="{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:{{ new_path }}"'
  when: "new_path not in ansible_env.PATH"
```

To see changes (reload PATH) add below task to Reset SSH connection

```
- name: Reset SSH Connection
  ansible.builtin.meta: reset_connection
```